# php pass data to next html page between different server

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using two free hoisting, one is 000WebXXXXX and another one is google drive.
All server-side things will be saved in 000Web and all html page will save in google drive.

The step of login: **login.html -> checkLogin.php -> mainPage.html**.

The login.html using form `method="POST"`to post data to checkLogin.php.
however, i have no idea how to pass data from php to html.

checkLogin.php:

```
//the server connection is omitted
if ($row["loginPassword"] == $passWord){
            header('Location: https://goo.gl/mainPage'); // go to next page 
        }else{
            echo "<h1>login Name or passWord is incorrect</h1>";
            echo "<a href='https://goo.gl/login'>login again</a>";// let user go back to login
        }
```

Comment: USE CURL POST TO TRANSFER DATA BETWEEN SERVERS

Comment: my   checkLogin.php will pass member_id, name to mainpage.html

Comment: Your mainpage needs to be a php page in order to process dynamic content.

Comment: you can load the page using php. Change the name of the HTML page as `.php` and then use `require` statement.

Comment: Is php just can return data,  not passing data?